# How to get current position of iterator in ByteString?

Tags: scala

I have an instance of `ByteString`. To read data from it I should use it's `iterator()` method.

I read some data and then I decide than I need to create a view (separate iterator of some chunk of data).

I can't use `slice()` of original iterator, because that would make it unusable, because docs says that:

> *After calling this method, one should discard the iterator it was called on, and use only the iterator that was returned. Using the old
>   iterator is undefined, subject to change, and may result in changes to
>   the new iterator as well.*

So, it seems that I need to call `slice()` on `ByteString`. But `slice()` has `from` and `until` parameters and I don't know `from`. I need something like this:

```
ByteString originalByteString = ...; // <-- This is my input data
ByteIterator originalIterator = originalByteString .iterator();
...
read some data from originalIterator
...
int length = 100; // < -- Size of the view
int from = originalIterator.currentPosition(); // <-- I need this
int until = from + length;
ByteString viewOfOriginalByteString = originalByteString.slice(from, until);
ByteIterator iteratorForView = viewOfOriginalByteString.iterator(); // <-- This is my goal
```

**Update:**

Tried to do this with `duplicate()`:

```
ByteIterator iteratorForView = originalIterator.duplicate()._2.take(length);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ByteIterator`'s `from` field is private, and none of the methods seems to simply return it. All I can suggest is to use `originalIterator.duplicate` to get a safe copy, or else to "cheat" by using reflection to read the `from` field, assuming reflection is available in your deployment environment.

Comment: But I don't want to copy data to get simple readonly view. Reflection is slow. Maybe I can get view another way?

Comment: You're not copying the data, just the iterator.